# Solving an equation with $x$ as powers

Tags: exponentiation

How would I go about solving $$2^x -2^{x-2}=3 *2^{13}$$Hints please. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT: Factor: $2^x-2^{x-2}=2^{x-2}(2^2-1)$.

Comment: I just solve it before you posted your hint. Thanks anyway)

Comment: @Dostre: You’re welcome. (And good.)